# Find tables name in multi-part identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I’m trying to select various table and column names from a (SQL Server 2008) database. The database is fairly big. There are several databases sitting on the same server, each with various schemas etc. Once there’s a multi-part identifier involved I’m stuck. For example, to retrieve a list of tables in under a database this works fine:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM DatabaseOne.sys.tables
ORDER BY [name]
```

Then I want to get the tables under a certain schema. E.g.:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM DatabaseOne.SchemaOne.sys.tables
ORDER BY [name]
```

But I get the error:

> Could not find server 'DatabaseOne' in sys.servers. Verify that the
>   correct server name       was specified. If necessary, execute the
>   stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

A large part of the problem probably lies in the fact that I don’t really know anything about schemas (if that’s even what they are).

Also, if I want to find the column names in a table, say DatabaseOne.SchemaOne.TableOne, how would I go about doing that?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: sys is a schema, so there is no such thing as yourschema.sys.tables (nor is there such a thing as yourschema.tables, at least not in the built-in metadata - you could create such a table yourself, but it will not be maintained by SQL Server). sys.tables (as JNK pointed out) contains all user tables, regardless of the schema.

Comment: I had no idea what _sys_ was really. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a four part name, SQL Assumes the first portion is the name of a linked server.

The system tables are in the `sys` schema, and contain data for all other schemas like `dbo` or whatever.

In `sys.tables` there is a `schema_id` value that specifies which schema each table is in.  There is also a `sys.schemas` table which contains the schemas.

If you know your schema name, you can do a

```
SELECT [name]
FROM DatabaseOne.sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
    ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE s.name = 'MySchema'
ORDER BY [name]
```

You can also check multiple schemas by making the `s.name` evaluation an `IN` evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had to modify it slightly to work. The schemas under _DatabaseOne_ do not seem to appear in _sys.schemas_. But they do under _DatabaseOne.sys.schemas_. For anyone who may be reading this topic in the future this worked for me:

`SELECT t.[name]
FROM DatabaseOne.sys.tables t
INNER JOIN DatabaseOne.sys.schemas s
    ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE s.name = 'MySchema'
ORDER BY t.[name]`.

Thank you JNK. EDIT: Formatting.

Comment: @Structured - you may need to fully qualify your metadata tables (`sys.schemas`, etc).  If you execute in the context of another DB it won't work, which sounds like what happened.